# VIM [new file] message appears when file already exists

Tags: vim, vi

I'm trying to view the following node logs on my server:

[image]

However, when I run `vim 2020-10-11T00_31_14_122Z-debug.log` - It's creating a new file rather than acknowledging the existing one:

[image]

Am I missing something blatantly trivial?

Comment: Does `cat` on the file work?

Comment: @resiliware no, running `cat 2020-10-11T00_31_14_122Z-debug.log` returns the following `cat: 2020-10-11T00_31_14_122Z-debug.log: No such file or directory`

Comment: (1). When you were typing the command, does your shell's auto completion return anything?     (2). Try `:r !ls` in a new `vim`, and check if new lines added, or if there're any weird characters.

Comment: paste the output of `sed -n l <<< $(ls)`.

Comment: I would guess you are not typing the name correctly, perhaps because there is a strange character or whitespace you're not recognizing. Perhaps try `vim $(ls | head -n 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure you are running the code from the correct folder or the path leads you to the file you want, once the path is correct you might use auto-complete which will give you the file easier and faster.